# How do I put a simple filter on an ionic 4 app ion-list

Tags: angular, ionic4, angular-pipe

I have a list that loops through keys of a SQlite db using ionic storage.  I use the Angular slice to omit the first to rows.  I also want to omit a row with the name of a_images.  I would prefer not to use a pipe for a single text item.  If I am I forced to use a pipe, what would the basic code inside the pipe even look like for a single text item?

html

```
<ion-list lines="inset">
  <ion-item *ngFor="let i of loop  | slice:2">
    <ion-label>{{i}}</ion-label>
    <ion-button fill="outline" color="success" slot="end" (click)="openKeyValue( i )">Open</ion-button>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

ts

```
// Traverse key/value pairs

listKeys() {
  this.storage.keys().then((k) => {
    console.table(k);
    this.loop = k;
    console.log("key value", this.loop);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put special case code into your loop with an `*ngIf`.

Something like:

```
<ion-list lines="inset">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let i of loop  | slice:2">
    <ion-item *ngIf="i !== 'a_images'">
      <ion-label>{{i}}</ion-label>;
      <ion-button fill="outline" color="success" slot="end" (click)="openKeyValue( i )">Open</ion-button>
    </ion-item>
  </ng-container>
</ion-list>
```

Alternatively you can pre-filter your data before you assign it to `this.loop` with something like:

```
this.loop = this.loop.filter(key => key !== 'a_images');
```

Comment: Works, but I Had to move *ngIf="i !== 'a_images'" to a new item.  Looks you cannot have *ngFor and *ngIf on the same item

Comment: Ah I wasn't sure off the top of my head. I know you can use `i` on same tag, so if you were binding it to something you could say `<ion-item *ngFor="let i of loop  | slice:2" [someVal]="i">`, using it on the same tag.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the `ng-container` as a wrapper - this doesn't output any html tag so its the cleanest way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code.

```
<ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let i of loop | slice:2">
  <ion-item  *ngIf="i !== 'a_images'">
    <ion-label>{{i}}</ion-label>
    <ion-button fill="outline" color="success" slot="end" (click)="openKeyValue( i )">Open</ion-button>
  </ion-item>
    <ion-item-options side="end">
      <ion-item-option (click)="deleteKeyValue( i )" color="danger">
        <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="trash"></ion-icon>
      </ion-item-option>
    </ion-item-options>
  </ion-item-sliding>
```

Comment: damn that's cold man, you took my answer to fix your code, then two days later took the rep off me :P

Comment: I just put you back.  I have no idea how that happened

Comment: Message me to let me know if I was succesful in getting you updated

Comment: :) thanks, it only lets you mark one question as an answer and you can remark it afterwards so i guess it got tapped somehow

Comment: Yeah I must have done that, anyways upvoted some of your other answers also